# How would I fix the issue of the python extension loading and Extension activation failed messages appearing?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, loading

[image]
[image]

I keep on getting these messages on the bottom right corner of my screen when opening up VS code. Any idea on how to get rid of it?

I can still write code and run the code fine but I don't understand why this is happening.

I've tried by deleting the python extension and anything related to python in the video extensions tab, but no luck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please update the [python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) to the *latest* version

[image]

or install the *pre-release* version directly. *( may be more useful to you )*

[image]

this will basically solve your problem.

**If the error continues, follow these steps:**

> 1. Uninstall Python extension (if you have pylance uninstall it first). Uninstall any other extension that is failing.
> 2. Close all instances of VS Code.
> 3. Go to, %USERPROFILE%/.vscode/extensions (on windows) or ~/.vscode/extensions on Linux/Mac.
> 4. Delete any folder with the name starting with ms-python.python*
> 5. Start VS Code, and install Python extension (also pylance if you uninstalled it in step 1).

Comment: This does not work, and no matter what `Python extension loading...` is continually displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and tried the above answer and it still didn't work. It turns out I hadn't installed python on my system yet. I didn't realize because I normally use it remotely.

From the VSCode documentation:

Quick start
Step 1. Install a supported version of Python on your system (note: that the system install of Python on macOS is not supported).
Step 2. Install the Python extension for Visual Studio Code.
Step 3. Open or create a Python file and start coding!