# VSCode Function App debug cant find task 'func: host start'

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to locally debug a Azure Function App (Python) using VS Code in WSL, Ubuntu 22.04. Unfortunately though, debugging doesn't seem to work.

I have installed and following pre-requisites -

- Azure extension (and logged in)
- Azure Functions extension (and created a Function App project using <kbd>Ctl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> -> Azure Functions: Create New Project...)
- Installed `azurite` (and started using <kbd>Ctl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> -> Azurite: Start)
- Ensure ***local.settings.json*** is configured with `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"`

But when I try to debug using the launch configuration **Attach to Python Functions** from ***.vscode/launch.json*** (added when I created a Function App project), an error message is displayed.

> Cound not find the task 'func: host start'.
> [image]

Using <kbd>Ctl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> and searching for 'func' does support that the task is missing.

However, on the CLI I can confirm that Azure Function App Tools is installed.

```bash
user@computer:~$ func --version
4.0.5198
```

I don't have the Python extension installed for two reasons -

- It's already installed at the version I require through WSL.
- Installing it makes the debugger not work - it just freezes and 'Python extension loading...' is displayed in the tool bar forever. Nothing is displayed in the 'Python' output. I have attempted the fix as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72791043/how-would-i-fix-the-issue-of-the-python-extension-loading-and-extension-activati), but it does not work.

How can I get a Function App to reliably debug using VS Code?

Comment: had the same problem  which disappeared after a few updates of all and everything. For the debugging part I don't like VSCode at all so did that with spyder for code parts. I know it doesn't help. Just a hint it may be related to the installation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the problem"Python extension loading..." in visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65301647/how-to-solve-the-problempython-extension-loading-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: @KiranShahi, you mean the accepted solution that I had already referenced in my answer below? Yep! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was entirely because the Python extension was not installed.

As described in the question, I was unable to use the Python extension because it would not start, and the solutions I had tried failed to fix the extension.

Happily I have now found the answer in another [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69597553/567059). Simply disabling telemetry worked in user settings has worked.

```json
"telemetry.telemetryLevel": "all|error|crash|off"
```

Comment: I should add, after further investigation it seems that the telemetry was failing when being sent over my organisations corporate VPN.